# JS - add selected or checked depending on input type

Tags: javascript, forms

When iterating through form options I'm setting their option to default based on their value.

As I have both select and radio/checkboxes - there are two ways of setting default values - selected/checked. Is there any way to simplify with pure JS - that will get both select and check?

```
if (param.type.select) {
          this.form.querySelector('[value="' + optionKey+'"]').selected = true;
        } else {
          this.form.querySelector('[value="' + optionKey+'"]').checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: You can use `this.form.querySelector(...)[param.type.select ? "selected" : "checked"] = true;`, not sure if that's an improvement though :)

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this and I think that's because option/select and inputs have some fundamentally different behavior. I would set the `value` of the select (and not the option) and the `checked` of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use `checked` for all 3 input types</strike>. You can use `checked` for all 3 input types for *reading* the selected or checked value. For *setting* the selected option you need the `selected`-attribute.

```js
// method to set selected or checked
const setSelected = (el, isSelect) => el[isSelect ? "selected" : "checked"] = true;

// initializing values for select, checkboxes and radio buttons
['3', 'cb3', 'r2'].forEach( v => {
  const elem = document.querySelector(`[value='${v}']`);
  elem && 
    (['checkbox', 'radio'].find(v => elem.type === v) ||
      elem.parentNode.options) && 
    setSelected(elem, elem.parentNode.options);
});

// add change handler
document.addEventListener("change", showValues);

function showValues() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`selected option value: ${
    document.querySelector("select option:checked").value}`);
  document.querySelectorAll("input:checked")
    .forEach( v => console.log(`value of checked ${v.type}: ${v.value}`) );
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>opt 0</option>
  <option value="1">opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">opt 3</option>
<select>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" value="cb1">cb 1
<input type="checkbox" value="cb2">cb 2
<input type="checkbox" value="cb3">cb 3
</p>
<input type="radio" name="x" value="r1"> r1
<input type="radio" name="x" value="r2"> r2
<input type="radio" name="x" value="r3"> r3
```

Comment: This behavior does not appear to be backed up by [the HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmloptionelement), which only defines a `selected` IDL attribute. It may very well work, but is not guaranteed to work by any specification.

Comment: I upvoted because I trust you the code runs but the spec doesn't indicate this should generally work https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmloptionelement

Comment: Sorry, downvoted, I thought this works but this only works because your HTML has `selected` set on the third option, if you edit the code snippet this doesn't work. You will note `.checked = true` doesn't actually do anything on the `option`.

Comment: In my experience most moder browsers support this. This code works at least in Firefox, Edge and Chrome.

Comment: @KooiInc this code doesn't work in Chrome. This only works because in your HTML the `option` is already `selected`.

Comment: @KooiInc confirmed, chrome [has no concept](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/forms/html_option_element.idl) of `.checked` on HTMLOptionElement nor [code to react to it](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/forms/html_option_element.h). The only related thing is [`:checked` being set](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/forms/html_option_element.cc;l=244).